# how to make full screen listview rows

Tags: listview, fullscreen

i have a listview in my application that i want make its rows full screen.

i set every thing to match_parent but it didn't work.

it just take half of screen.

how can i must do this?

it is my listview code:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listviewFactoriPortfolio"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>
```

and it is my custom layout for each row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgImageItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/photo_2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtNameItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtExplainItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtNameItem"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtCostItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgImageItem"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtDestributeDateItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txtCostItem"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtAddressItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txtDestributeDateItem"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="Small Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this in getView() of your adapter :

```
view.getLayoutParams().height = viewGroup.getHeight() / getCount();
view.requestLayout();
```